# Pointing posters to an alternative forum for how to questions?

Tags: discussion

I understand that sfse is not the place to ask general how to / is this possible questions, as one needs to provide specific info on what was tried and what issue they are having.

With that said, i think we should point people to a specific place when we tell them that this isn't the place to ask their question.

I think the success aka trailblazer community, and ideally a specific chatter group, is a good option in many cases.

I'm thinking of this question in specific, which is something I see pop up pretty frequently (for a flow question) and I think could actually be a good community wiki, but understand that it doesn't meet these guidelines.

[Review screen that shows details of created record(s) and related record(s) at end of Flow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/196157/10062)

Comment: I agree with you, I think we can help by pointing them to the trailblazer community groups that are relevant and I've certainly done that with Trailhead questions.

Comment: One thing that makes it tough is if you are not familiar with any of the alternatives and don't really know what would be a better fit for the OP.